# Suggestions for vehicle sensors for parking lots

Tags: sensors

I am looking for wireless vehicle sensors that could be laid out on the ground to detect if a parking spot is occupied or not.

I am looking for sensors that can integrate with any of the IoT backends i.e. major public cloud platforms, are reliable and of course economical so that we can scale the solution.Can someone recommend any vendor products that fit the bill ?

The use case is to implement a simple parking counter/display based on the parking availability from the parking /vehicle sensors.

The connectivity type could be cellular3G/4G or LoraWAN as long as it is economical.

Comment: Welcome. Great question; I will be watching it. But, you might actually get a better reply on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think this sort of design brainstorming question is in scope for this site. There is a spectrum of what is 'answerable', but I don't think this is anywhere near that - it is much more of a open ended shopping question.

Comment: I know it could be viewed as a 'shopping question' , but it is more of a research question for someone starting into it and wants to make a informed decision based on support of open standards, compatibility , reliability ,efficiency etc. I am glad you did not ask for it to be closed like most of the admins in stack exchange communities do .

Comment: your question is specifically a shopping recommendation request .... it would not be a shopping question if you asked about what sensor technologies are available .... once you know the technology involved, you could search for vendors that use the desired technology in their products

Comment: Hi @DynaObjectLLC, while it might be debatable if it's a shopping/brainstorming/ideation/recommendation question this is definitely to far away from a specific project in regards of criteria which would set boundaries for any answer. Starting—and really only starting—with the question, what would that sensor do with that information, i.e. what's your IoT use case and what connectivity are you planning (4/5G, local connectivity, directed lasers, quantum entanglement)?

Comment: Hi @Helmar , the use case is to implement a simple parking counter/display based on the parking availability from the parking /vehicle sensors. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Helmar the connectivity type could be cellular3G/4G or LoraWAN as long as it is economical.

Comment: Please add these information to your question via [edit] if you think this is a good fit for this Stack Exchange site.

Comment: If you do give more details, then maybe the question will no longer be too board and will be reopened

Comment: If I had more details , I would have went ahead and purchased it myself, everyone here is taking their job too seriously , to the point where they stifle free exchange of information.

Comment: @DynaObjectLLC You can use magnetic sensors; when placed in the middle of a parking spot you'll get a measurement orders of magnitude larger when a vehicle is parked. This can involve drilling into pavement to place sensors/batteries, and detecting motorcycles/bikes can be harder because they are smaller. The other option is some sort of optical or SONAR beam from above the space to the ground...when an obstruction is detected, something is parked there. This also tends to be an expensive install because you need an overhead rack system.

Comment: Both are not ideal solutions when edge cases are involved. What if someone parks over the line and a space is now only accessible by a very small car? Or someone's bumper falls off and gets left in the space? Image processing would be most accurate, but even more expensive